# Google map only appears for second on website

Tags: google-maps

I placed code on my website to show a map, it works but map only appears 1 second then disappears

Searched year and tried solutions that did not work

```
<div id="map"></div> 
    <script> 
      function initMap() { 
        var test= {lat: 42.988195, lng: -81.246134}; 
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), { 
          zoom: 12, 
          center: test 
        }); 
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ 
          position: test, 
          map: map 
        }); 
      } 
    </script> 
    <script async defer 
    src= 
"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=(KEY)&callback=initMap"> 
    </script>
```

Comment: Please link to the problem page.

Comment: Link is at http://mobile.dogoodperks.com/2018/?goto=RestSample now this page is meant to be mobile but you can see it is not working

Comment: It seems you don't active your API key. You need to enable Google Maps JavaScript v3 BEFORE api key generating.

Comment: If you already enable Google Maps JavaScript v3, generate a new API key, then try with it.

Comment: OMG that was so easy thank you so much

Comment: You are welcome :)

Comment: spoke too soon now it states that "this page cannot load maps" and map is faded why

Comment: You need to allow your website for the key.

Answer (score 0):

Open developer tools at your page.
If you use Google Chrome, Menu > View > Developer > JavaScript Console.

There is message from Google Maps API "**RefererNotAllowedMapError**"

[image]